# Pyspark adding a column of repeating values from a list

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe and want to add a column that adds values from a list in a repeating fashion.  If this were just python, I would probably use itertools' cycle function.  I don't know how to do this in pyspark.

```
names = ['Julia', 'Tim', 'Zoe']
```

My dataframe looks like this:

```
+-----+------+
| id_A| idx_B|
+-----+------+
|    a|     0|       
|    b|     0|    
|    b|     2|       
|    b|     2|       
|    b|     2|       
|    b|     2|      
+-----+------+
```

I want it to look like this:

```
+-----+------+--------+
| id_A| idx_B| names  |
+-----+------+--------+
|    a|     0|   Julia|
|    b|     0|     Tim|
|    b|     2|     Zoe|
|    b|     2|   Julia|
|    b|     2|     Tim|
|    b|     2|     Zoe|
+-----+------+--------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way.

1 - add a unique incremental id for your dataframe:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    df.rdd.zipWithIndex().map(lambda x: Row(*x[0], x[1]))
).toDF("id_A", "idx_B", "id")

df.show()
#+----+-----+---+
#|id_A|idx_B| id|
#+----+-----+---+
#|   a|    0|  0|
#|   b|    0|  1|
#|   b|    2|  2|
#|   b|    2|  3|
#|   b|    2|  4|
#|   b|    2|  5|
#+----+-----+---+
```

2 - create dataframe from the list of names:

```
names_df = spark.createDataFrame([(idx, name) for idx, name in enumerate(names)], ["name_id", "names"])
```

3 - join using modulo 3 (length of names list) in condition:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

result = df.join(
    names_df,
    F.col("id") % 3 == F.col("name_id")
).orderBy("id").drop("id", "name_id")

result.show()
#+----+-----+-----+
#|id_A|idx_B|names|
#+----+-----+-----+
#|   a|    0|Julia|
#|   b|    0|  Tim|
#|   b|    2|  Zoe|
#|   b|    2|Julia|
#|   b|    2|  Tim|
#|   b|    2|  Zoe|
#+----+-----+-----+
```